# In localhost extension Install giving error in magento 2.2.5

Tags: extensions, magento-2.2.5

How to solve this error.

I'm running magento 2.2.5 in my localhost in Ubuntu. I want to install extension, but unable to install due to this error. I gave full permission as 777 to my folder. But still error showing.

I'm little confuse on it how to solve. Please help. Waste my all day, but unable to solve.

[image]

Comment: extract zip of extension and put in app/code and run command php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: I think you should use composer to install module